# How can I know what is cached with django cachalot on my server?

Tags: python, django, caching

I have Django with Django Cachalot and I need know what is cached with cachalot in my server? I want to use `CACHALOT_UNCACHABLE_TABLES` parameter and I need to know if this works and certain tables are not cached. I hope that somebody can help me, thank you.

I initialized the parameter like this: `CACHALOT_UNCACHABLE_TABLES = frozenset(('django_migrations', 'company_company', 'customers_customer, 'auth_user'))`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Correctly, I checked this. If you use `CACHALOT_UNCACHABLE_TABLES` setting this variable with the table names that tables doesn't cache with Cachalot.

Comment: Hi, your answer doesn't mention how you checked if the tables are being avoided or not? Can you please update your answer?

Comment: I checked it 3 years ago and I don't remember well, but I guess you can use the Django debugging toolbar to analyze whether or not Django makes the queries every time. https://pypi.org/project/django-debug-toolbar/